# Остановить генератор

Tags: python, рекурсия, генераторы, yield

Функция генерирует определённую последовательность чисел в виде списка списков. Вопрос, как остановить этот генератор, когда длинна основного списка будет больше двух.

```py
def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[], partial_sum=0):

    s = [i**2 for i in partial]

    if sum(s) == target**2:
        yield partial
    if sum(s) >= target**2:
        return None
    for i, n in enumerate(numbers):
        remaining = numbers[i + 1:]
        yield from subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n], partial_sum + n)

print(list(subset_sum(range(50, 0, -1),50)))
```

Comment: Основной список это какой?

Comment: Вот например, функция выводит такой список:
 [[11], [10, 4, 2, 1], [9, 6, 2], [8, 6, 4, 2, 1]] . Как остановить генератор, когда длинна списка будет два?
Просто, когда на вход подаются большие числа генератор очень долго работает, а мне надо только первые два элемента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) решает нужную задачу:

```
import itertools


def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[], partial_sum=0):
    ...


print(list(itertools.islice(subset_sum(range(50, 0, -1), 50), 2)))
```

> ```
> $ python subset_sum.py 
> [[50], [49, 8, 5, 3, 1]]
> ```

Comment: Станислав, Вы уже не первый раз мне даёте нужную наводку. Преклоняюсь перед Вашими знаниями Python. Спасибо огромное!